# Get login in token caonima

Tags: google-signin

I am calling Google login. I can't get the id token, but the contents of Email, id, etc. are available. I didn't register in firebase. I registered on the developer platform. What is the reason?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the stack and the API you want to use? What is Caonima? Can you also provide some code?

Comment: I am sorry, the Google logo calling credentials are using Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in) instead of OAuth client, but I can also get it with OAuth client. Can you tell me the purpose of OAuth client?